# How to correctly pause and resume a std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, stdthread

I'm new to multithreading in C++. I just want to define a class `TaskManager` that allows me to handle the execution of a general task. The core logic of the task should be implemented in the `task()` method. Then I want to implement the `start()`, `pause()`, and `resume()` methods to handle the execution of `task()`. Is there any problem with this implementation? Is it the right way to handle this kind of problem? is there a way to abstract the core logic from the `task()` method?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>


class TaskManager{
private:
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::thread task_thread;
    bool paused = true;
    bool finished = false;
    int counter = 0;
    int MAX_COUNT = INT_MAX;

public:
    ~TaskManager(){
        if (this->task_thread.joinable()){
            this->task_thread.join();
        }
    }
    void task(){
        // Finishing condition. ==> counter < this->MAX_COUNT
        while(counter < this->MAX_COUNT){
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(this->mtx);
            this->cv.wait(ul, [this] {return (!this->paused);});

            // CORE LOGIC...
            counter++;

        }
        std::cout << "Finished!" << std::endl;
        this->finished = true;
    }
    void start(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(this->mtx);
        this->paused = false;
        task_thread = std::thread([this]{this->task();});
        cv.notify_one();
    }
    void pause(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(this->mtx);
        if (!this->finished) {
            this->paused = true;
            this->cv.notify_one();
        }
    }
    void resume(){
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ul(this->mtx);
        if (!this->finished) {
            this->paused = false;
            this->cv.notify_one();
        }
    }
    int getCounter() {
        return this->counter;
    }

};

int main() {
    TaskManager tm;
    std::cout << "counter before start(): " << tm.getCounter() << std::endl;
    tm.start();

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    std::cout << "counter after 10 ms: " << tm.getCounter() << std::endl;

    tm.pause();
    std::cout << "counter after pause(): " << tm.getCounter() << std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    std::cout << "counter after 10 ms: " << tm.getCounter() << std::endl;

    tm.resume();
    std::cout << "counter after resume(): " << tm.getCounter() << std::endl;

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
    std::cout << "counter after 10 ms: " << tm.getCounter() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
counter before start(): 0
counter after 10 ms: 266967
counter after pause(): 267526
counter after 10 ms: 267526
counter after resume(): 267526
counter after 10 ms: 487041
Finished!
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean?

Comment: Setting a variable called `pause` to true will not magically pause your task. You could for example periodically check its value during the computation and go to sleep (wait on the CV) if you see it activated.

Comment: The output you have posted obviously does not correspond to the code you have posted. Also, undefined behavior for unsynchronized, non-readonly, non-atomic access to an object from multiple threads.

Comment: BTW, you have a _data race_ on `counter`. It should be atomic. Otherwise, it can be set only once to its final value without any increments. Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Kh576d4zo.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I changed the code (and edited the post accordingly) and now it seems to work as expected, is there still any data race problem?

Comment: @ИванКарамазов I don't see that you made `counter` an atomic variable. Yes, you can use a mutex as well (which less efficiency), but then you need to protect reading as well in `getCounter()` function.

Comment: Looks better. If you want to better separate concerns, you might consider a `void checkPaused() const` method to break that logic out, much like `std::stop_token` has a `stop_requested` method: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/stop_token/stop_requested

At a very high level, I'm dubious of the notion of a pause-able thread.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I will investigate atomic variables too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any problem with this implementation?

- There's data race on `counter`
- You probably don't want to hold the lock while executing `// CORE LOGIC...`. If you mean to protect `counter`, you should prefer another mutex for it.
- `finished` should be under the lock too. Alternatively, it could be atomic. Note that unnecessary notifications don't hurt, so you can sip `finished` altogether

> Is it the right way to handle this kind of problem?

Depending on why do you want to pause in the first place. For some reasons to pause there could be a better approach, like C++20 `latch`/`semaphore`/`barrier`.

> is there a way to abstract the core logic from the task() method?

To what extent. You can change it to

```
void CoreLogic(std::function<void()> pause_callback) {
   pause_callback();
   // Core logic
}
```

You cannot pause a thread in an arbitrary point with C++ facilities. Maybe you can with platform facilities (like, Windows has `SuspendThread`), but it may not be a good idea (imagine a thread acquires `malloc` internal lock when paused).